# Proving a polynomial has x amount of zeros

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

I am new to this thread so sorry if I violate any rules or whatever, but anyway in Calculus right now we are doing stuff related to Fermat's Theorem, Rolle's Theorem, and Intermediate value theorem. I am very confused by Rolles and Fermats and totally don't understand them I try looking online just to be more perplexed than resolved. In our homework it is full of problems like this:

> Prove $y = x^3-6x^2+12x-8$ has at most two zeros.
>
> Prove $f(x)=x^5+5x^3+45x+9$ has exactly one zero.

I am just totally lost on what to do and how to begin I really don't understand how to prove these with the theorems given.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The answer to this question rather depends on what you mean by a zero and how you count. There is implicit in your question an assumption that you are counting distinct real zeros. For some (important) purposes, multiple zeros are counted with multiplicity, and complex numbers are allowed as zeros.

Comment: First hint: $\;y = (x-2)^3\,$. Second hint: each of $x^5$, $x^3$ and $x$ is strictly increasing on $\,\mathbb{R}\,$.

Comment: Example: $f(x) = x^{3} - 6x^{2} + 12x - 8$, $f(0) = -8<0$ and $f(3) = 1>0$, then by IVT, theres exits $c \in (0, 3)$ such that $f(c) = 0$. Remember that if $z$ is a complex root, $\bar{z} $ is a complex root.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is that between any two zeros of your function the derivative must have at least one zero.

$1)$  Prove $$ y=x^3−6x^2+12x−8$$ has at most two zeros.

If a polynomial has three zeros, then its derivative must have at least two zeros due to Rolle's Theorem. Taking derivative of  $$ y=x^3−6x^2+12x−8$$ We get   $$ y=3x^2−12x+12 =3(x-2)^2$$

Which has only one zero.

$2)$ Prove $$f(x)=x^5+5x^3+45x+9$$ has exactly one zero.

It has one zero because its degree is odd so it changes sign from negative to positive as as x goes from $- \infty $ to $\infty$

Taking derivative of   $$f(x)=x^5+5x^3+45x+9$$  we get$$5x^4+15x^2+45$$ which is always positive and has no zeros.

Thus the function is increasing and has only one zero.

Answer (score 1):

i) $f(x) = x^3-6x^2+12x-8$.

Suppose that $f$ has $3$ zeroes in $a<b<c$.

How $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=0%$ then, by Rolle's Theorem, there is a zero of $f'(x)$ in interval $(a, b)$ and another zero in $(b, c)$. In other words, $f'(x)$ has two zeroes. But $f'(x) = 3x^2-12x+12 = 3(x-2)^2$ has only one zero. Contradiction!

Therefore $f$ has at most two zeroes.

ii) $f(x) = x^5+5x^3+45x+9$

How $f$ has odd degree, then $f$ has at least one zero.

Note that $f'(x) = 5x^4+15x^2+45 > 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that $f$ has two zeroes in $a<b$. By Rolle's Theorem, should exists $c$ with $a<c<b$ such that $f'(c)=0$. Contradiction!

Therefore $f$ has exactly one zero.